# Parallel writes to xlsxwriter worksheet slower than sequential writes

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, xlsxwriter

I wanted to write to multiple worksheets of the same workbook at the same time. 
The code is as follows:

```
import threading
import xlsxwriter
import time


def write_to_w1(w1, data):
    print('task1 executing....')
    for row, item in enumerate(data):
        w1.write(row, 0, item, row_format)

def write_to_w2(w2, data):
    print('task2 executing....')
    for row, item in enumerate(data):
        w2.write(row, 0, item, row_format)

def write_to_w3(w3, data):
    print('task3 executing....')
    for row, item in enumerate(data):
        w3.write(row, 0, item, row_format)


start = time.time()
data1 = [i for i in range(0,500000)]
data2 = [i for i in range(0,500000)]
data3 = [i for i in range(0,500000)]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('~/Desktop/threading.xlsx')
row_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': False, 'align': 'left', 'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'vcenter'})
w1 = workbook.add_worksheet('w1')
w2 = workbook.add_worksheet('w2')
w3 = workbook.add_worksheet('w3')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=write_to_w1, args=(w1, data1), name='t1')
t2 = threading.Thread(target=write_to_w2, args=(w2, data2), name='t2')
t3 = threading.Thread(target=write_to_w3, args=(w3, data3), name='t3')

# starting thread 1
t1.start()
# starting thread 2
t2.start()
# starting thread 3
t3.start()

# wait until thread 1 is completely executed
t1.join()
# wait until thread 2 is completely executed
t2.join()
# wait until thread 3 is completely executed
t3.join()

# both threads completely executed
print("Done!")
workbook.close()
end = time.time()
print('total time ==>', end-start)
```

Upon benchmarking with sequential execution, **the parallel version took around 52secs and sequential version took 50secs to execute**.

What is causing this performance degradation? Is synchronization the issue or is writing to a single workbook an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that counts as degradation. The time span is long enough where other processes could interfere and I'm  not sure that the percent difference is significant.

Comment: What exactly was your benchmark by the way? How many total runs did you have, and what was the *fastest* run in each category?

Comment: The actual method were calls to functions sequenctially one after the other. Number of runs was just once.

Comment: Although i did run this multiple times to double check. Turned out the same each time

Comment: write a smaller amount of data, say something that takes 1 sec, run it 100 times and select the minimum.

Comment: I'm not surprised that the parallel case takes a tiny bit longer because of the global lock, but I would expect the difference to be milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: Also, if it was using multi-processing under the hood, copying back the data would take a long time. I don't think that's the case here though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In normal operation xlsxwriter stores data in memory and at the `close()` stage it writes that data to files and then zips those files. The file writing operations count for the bulk of the execution time in any reasonably large xlsxwriter program.

The reason that you don't see a speed up is probably due to the fact that the threads have rejoined by the time it gets to the `close()` part of the program.

I thought that using `{'constant_memory': True}` in the constructor might get better performance from the threaded version since it uses intermediary files instead of memory. However with a quick test using your program, it doesn't.

A better way to speed up a large xlsxwriter program is to use [pypy](https://pypy.org/). For the non-threaded version of your program the execution time of a reference system goes from 46.7s (Python2) to 8.2s (PyPy) or almost 6x faster.

In fact pypy gives performance close to the pure C implementation of xlsxwriter [libxlsxwriter](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/) which is roughly 10x faster than the Python version for larger data sets.

Comment: So this turns out to be a limitation of python. What do u reckon would be the performance if xlsxwriter is replaced with openpyxl?

Comment: Performance of openpyxl and xlsxwriter should be roughly the same.

Comment: Using pypy, the execution time is reduced down to 17secs (~3x times faster)